# Error deploying express project on heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, npm, deployment

i'm deploying my first app on heroku, i pushed the code on GitHub, add Heroku keys(because ), created the heroku app on terminal and finally git push heroku master.

The app is very basic, but it doesn't work, and i can't even find a decent log information to work with!

This is the long log that i found.
Hope someone could help me!

```
2019-12-06T00:11:00.862870+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10) {
2019-12-06T00:11:00.862872+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2019-12-06T00:11:00.862874+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/src/app.js' ]
2019-12-06T00:11:00.862876+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2019-12-06T00:11:00.870032+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-12-06T00:11:00.871330+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-12-06T00:11:00.871733+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 1-Heroku@1.0.0 start: `node src/app.js`
2019-12-06T00:11:00.872684+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-12-06T00:11:00.872690+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-12-06T00:11:00.872695+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 1-Heroku@1.0.0 start script.
2019-12-06T00:11:00.872698+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-12-06T00:11:02.538864+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-06T00:11:02.542433+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-12-06T00:11:02.542703+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-12-06T00_11_00_875Z-debug.log
2019-12-06T00:11:02.625046+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-12-06T00:11:02.614891+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-12-06T00:18:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user cristiano.piscioneri.dev@gmail.com
2019-12-06T00:18:24.105108+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=c-neri-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=b779201e-bb33-420a-9aea-cd67d026040e fwd="151.32.4.219" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-12-06T00:18:48.614900+00:00 app[api]: Deploy c57e0dc3 by user cristiano.piscioneri.dev@gmail.com
2019-12-06T00:18:48.614900+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user cristiano.piscioneri.dev@gmail.com
2019-12-06T00:18:48.892841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-12-06T00:18:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-12-06T00:18:52.277413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-12-06T00:18:55.506035+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-06T00:18:55.506063+00:00 app[web.1]: > 1-Heroku@1.0.0 start /app
2019-12-06T00:18:55.506065+00:00 app[web.1]: > node src/app.js
2019-12-06T00:18:55.506067+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809888+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809932+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809934+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809936+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809939+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'hbs'
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809941+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809943+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/src/app.js
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809945+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809947+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809950+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809952+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809954+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/app.js:5:13)
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809956+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809958+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809960+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809962+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809964+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10) {
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809966+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809968+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/src/app.js' ]
2019-12-06T00:18:55.809970+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2019-12-06T00:18:55.853916+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-12-06T00:18:55.854597+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-12-06T00:18:55.858952+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 1-Heroku@1.0.0 start: `node src/app.js`
2019-12-06T00:18:55.859163+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-12-06T00:18:55.859694+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-12-06T00:18:55.859697+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 1-Heroku@1.0.0 start script.
2019-12-06T00:18:55.859764+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-12-06T00:18:55.917128+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-06T00:18:55.917132+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-12-06T00:18:55.917135+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-12-06T00_18_55_860Z-debug.log
2019-12-06T00:18:56.015418+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-12-06T00:18:55.990556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-12-06T00:18:57.272264+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=c-neri-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=1371d608-aa3d-4ada-94bb-cde5f9edfd69 fwd="151.32.4.219" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-12-06T00:21:46.461037+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-12-06T00:21:49.272673+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-12-06T00:21:53.501754+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-12-06T00:21:53.116284+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-06T00:21:53.116306+00:00 app[web.1]: > 1-Heroku@1.0.0 start /app
2019-12-06T00:21:53.116308+00:00 app[web.1]: > node src/app.js
2019-12-06T00:21:53.116310+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306576+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306580+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306583+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306586+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306588+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'hbs'
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306591+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306596+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/src/app.js
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306598+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306600+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306603+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306605+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306607+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/app.js:5:13)
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306609+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306611+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306613+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306616+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306618+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10) {
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306620+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306622+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/src/app.js' ]
2019-12-06T00:21:53.306624+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2019-12-06T00:21:53.321267+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-12-06T00:21:53.321742+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-12-06T00:21:53.324564+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 1-Heroku@1.0.0 start: `node src/app.js`
2019-12-06T00:21:53.324972+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-12-06T00:21:53.325528+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-12-06T00:21:53.326031+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 1-Heroku@1.0.0 start script.
2019-12-06T00:21:53.326436+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-12-06T00:21:53.342561+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-06T00:21:53.342869+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-12-06T00:21:53.343077+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-12-06T00_21_53_327Z-debug.log
2019-12-06T00:21:53.479134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-12-06T00:22:24.106302+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=c-neri-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=fbd6f731-b6f7-49c1-b1ed-2373fd79d7d1 fwd="151.32.4.219" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-12-06T00:31:08.844509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=c-neri-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=f109e557-116b-4915-8c50-82520f635a42 fwd="151.32.4.219" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

my app.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const appRoute = require('./routes/app.js')
const hbs = require( 'hbs')
const port = process.env.PORT||3001

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname + '../../public')
const partialsPath = path.join(__dirname + '/template/partials')
const viewPath = path.join(__dirname + '/template/views')

//HBS
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views', viewPath)
hbs.registerPartials(partialsPath)

app.use(express.static(publicPath))


//ROUTES
app.use(appRoute)

app.listen(port)
```

my package.js script

```js
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "dev": "nodemon src/app.js",
    "start": "node src/app.js"
  },
```

Comment: Delete "node_modules" and reinstall it. Check if it works.

Comment: I don't know how to do deployment on heroku, but if it only loads application code without dependencies, then maybe you need to manually install dependencies on heroku?

Comment: thank you for your response, nothing changed, when i visit my heroku git url, i read "method not allowed"

Comment: Deleting my node_modules, in my new package.json there is a new object called repository, and now it works! Thank you!